# Why is my build breaking on the ng2-toasty module dependence?

Tags: angular

my project has a dependency on `ng2-toasty` and when I attempt to build I get the following error:

> An error occurred during the build: Error: The target entry-point
> "ng2-toasty" has missing dependencies:
>
> - rxjs/Observable
>
>   at TargetedEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (tst/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40:23)
>   at tst/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/analyze_entry_points.js:29:41
>   at SingleProcessExecutorSync.SingleProcessorExecutorBase.doExecute (tst/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:28:29)
>   at tst/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:57:59
>   at SyncLocker.lock (tst/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/locking/sync_locker.js:34:24)
>   at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (tst/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:57:27)
>   at Object.mainNgcc (tst/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/main.js:74:25)
>   at Object.process (tst/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/index.js:29:23)
>   at NgccProcessor.processModule (tst/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:175:16)
>   at tst/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/host.js:146:18
>   at tst/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/host.js:76:24
>   at Array.map ()
>   at Object.host.resolveModuleNames (tst/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/host.js:74:32)
>   at actualResolveModuleNamesWorker (tst/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:109497:133)
>   at resolveModuleNamesWorker (tst/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:109760:26)
>   at resolveModuleNamesReusingOldState (tst/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:109857:24) An unhandled
>   exception occurred: The target entry-point "ng2-toasty" has missing
>   dependencies:
> - rxjs/Observable

here's the relevant entry from my `package.json` dependencies clause:

```
package.json:    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
```

I'm not an angular guy... can anyone suggest what the problem might be? I find literally nothing on the web about this module, except the Git repo

Comment: ng2-toasty, last update 4 years ago. Have you considered using another dependency for toasts? The alternative would be to create a fork of the project, which I don't advise since you're not an angular guy

Comment: thanks guys.  @ChrisW you can post that as an answer and I will approve it

Comment: Done, and del'd original comment. Though possibly should have put it as a duplicate although the others don't directly reference `ng2-toasty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using [deprecated rxjs dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476091/import-of-observable-rxjs-observable-is-not-working) and would require [rxjs-compat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat) for backwards compatibility depending on your version....however like @CristianTraìna pointed out, strongly suggest instead trying a supported alternative and ditch the toasty and keep a habit of forward versioning in used components.